# Accessing subview variables from another subview

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, subview

I have a UIViewController with two sub UIViews. 
In the first UIView I created a UIView with a green background.
After pushing a button in the UIViewController I change this to a red background.

And now I want to change it to a purple background, but since i changed the background in the UIViewController I'm not able to change it (again).

**UIViewA.h**

```
@interface UIViewA : UIView

@property UIView *colorView;
```

**UIViewA.m**

```
...
colorView = [[UIView alloc]init];
[colorView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
...
```

**UIViewController.h**

```
#import "UIViewA.h"
#import "UIViewB.h"

@interface MainViewController : UIViewController

@property UIViewA *viewA;
@property UIViewB *viewB;
```

**UIViewController.m**

```
...
viewA = [[UIViewA alloc]init];
viewB = [[UIViewB alloc]init];
...

-(void)changeColor
{
    [[viewA colorView] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
}
```

**UIViewB.h**

```
#import "UIViewA.h"

@interface UIViewB : UIView

@property UIViewA *ViewA;
```

**UIViewB.m**

```
...
ViewA = [[UIViewA alloc]init];
[[ViewA colorView] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
// ^^ That rule doesn't seem to work. No errors were given.
...
```

**EDIT:**
A shorter example of what I'm trying to do.
[image]

Comment: If you want to change the color again, add another button in view controller, and make it do the job.

Comment: @CarouselMin, That won't solve my problem because the button needs to be in the second UIView.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right, you want to change viewA's background color in viewB. What you can do is in viewcontroller.m, after you have created viewB, assign `viewB.viewA = self.viewA`. and in viewB.m, do not create a new viewA, instead use the property self.viewA, thus you can change the viewA's background color. In `viewB.m`

```
[[self.viewA colorView] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
```

Comment: To bad, but this didn't work.

What I'm trying to do is, to edit a value in one file and store it in a way, that when I call this value in another file, it will return the new value.

Comment: Yes, it worked, after I changed viewA's colorView to red color, I get a red color from viewB.

Comment: @Maarten1909 think you might need to elaborate more in what you are trying to achieve here. CarouselMin's answer shows that the property you are accessing is on the exact same object (viewA's colorView) hence why you dont create a new viewA.

Comment: @IainSmith This didn't work for me because i edited viewA in the main view controller first. Every change that i make in view B changes a new instance of view A.

Comment: @Maarten1909 what are you trying to do here? Do you want every instance of UIViewA to have the same background color? background color is a property of UIViewA class, so each instance of UIViewA has a different background color.

Comment: @CarouselMin, maybe the image in the question will help you understand.